# Why don't I get reputation for reviewing questions?

Tags: feature-request, review

What does meta think of the idea of a single reputation point for reviewing questions?

- It would provide a maximum of 40 points a day and would count toward cap.
- Gives a little indication of thanks for the hard work of reviewing the close Q.
- 1 point per review doesnt seem like a huge amount and so shouldn't increase bad reviews

Any thoughts?

Comment: No! Not more incentive for roboreviewers, *please*!

Comment: Reputation shouldn't be an incentive to do review work, your caring for the community should be.

Comment: Looking at the abuse we experience from meaningless badges, this would only make the problem worse. We want people to review because they actually care about the site, not because they're going to get free points from it.

Comment: I like this, we can add -1 reputation for each review, which will be a strong deterrent for anyone not actually interested in helping out the site.  Those that are actually here to contribute won't be deterred, leaving the site with a much higher quality of reviews.

Comment: Then you should also put a system in place to have an automated way to deal with bad reviewer ([better audits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183977/add-too-minor-audits-to-review-queue/203728#203728), for example, and probably significant negative reputation for being 'dealt with').

Comment: @Dukeling We've been trying to deal with bad reviewers for *years* even *without* this feature, with only limited success.  If a really successful system for filtering out bad reviewers was going to happen, it likely would have happened already, and if it can happen, it should happen with or without this feature.

Comment: Wow -15 that's a no then!

Comment: @Servy: plus, for every 10 reviews you do, lose a random badge! :)

Comment: Related - [Review system reputation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/163814)

Comment: Very soon there shall be a proposal for giving reputation for _reading_ questions too.

Comment: @devnull I don't really think that's fair.  AS pointed out in the question that Dukeling linked to there is quite a bit of work in reviewing questions properly.  I take quite seriously the close Q and try to do some reviews every day (not 40, but I do have a Job).  I'm not looking for reputation for doing nothing, I'm asking about reputation for doing something.  The problem of robo reviewers is real and I understand that, but it is seperate.

Comment: @TobyAllen No, it's *not* separate.  This proposal would *vastly* exacerbate that problem, likely to the point of rendering the entire review system ineffective.  Based on past experiences, I'd say that we'd be better of deleting the review system entirely than we would be implementing this feature, and the reason is *precisely* because of those bad reviewers.

Comment: How about giving 5 [unicoins](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/unicoins/info) per review?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This wouldn't work because there are no inherent checks on whether someone's contribution is good.  The most successful gamification parts of the site, questions and answers, work because **you only get points when someone else judges your contribution useful**.

Put another way, imagine if you got a point for every question you posted.  The site would be flooded with crap questions immediately.  The only way these systems work is if there's some sort of feedback loop so that people can't just give themselves points.

Comment: What should we do when some person don't judge at all? Is there a question about it here? When you don't have a feedback.

Answer (score 24):

This would really increase bad reviews. There are already a lot of robo-reviewers just for the badges, and there will be a lot more of you also get rewarded by rep when reviewing. Giving robo-reviewers more rep will mean that they will get more privileges very fast, but they really don't deserve these privileges.