# Reputation for "correctly" triaging

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, reputation, review, triage

Triaging is a mostly thankless job, and I feel like a little bit of a reputation boost for "correctly" triaging (where correctly triaging is triaging in accordance with the final decision) would be nice. This should probably eventually apply to the other queues as well, but for triage it is clear what reputation should be given for.

Comment: We get badges. We get that warm feeling in our hearts that we did something good. More than enough in my opinion. :)

Comment: Neither badges nor warm feelings grant privileges, sadly.

Comment: Giving too much power will most likely cause much more robo reviewers, who are the greatest risk to the whole review system.

Comment: That is why I proposed we only reward "correct" triaging.

Comment: @Gaelan But "correct" triaging is defined in your question to be what the final decision is. If you have more robo-reviewers blindly clicking "Looks OK", then you'll have more "Looks OK" consensuses, which will be considered "correct" triaging.

Comment: @ArthurFischer True. Maybe if we award a semi-large hunk of rep per successful audit? While completing an audit causes no contribution to the community itself, you have to (in theory) carefully review many other questions before you pass an audit.

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229058).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, the entire point of the review queue is that there is no good measure of good and bad. Hence, we need humans, multiple of them, to review a case. That would make rewarding 'good' reviews almost impossible. Note that the end result of a review is not always the end result it should be, thanks to robo-reviewers.

Awarding reputation for reviewing is a bad idea. Not only for the above reason, also because it encourages robo-reviewing, something we definitely not want to have.

Comment: Imagine how much rep the top reviewer would have if this was implemented... or rather how much that user earned :)