# Award For Reviewing (Triage, First Posts, etc)

Tags: discussion, reputation, review, review-audits

As [stated before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268020/reputation-for-correctly-triaging), reviewing questions is a thankless job. The OP of that question had a good point. Today, I noticed the Triage feature for the first time. I've probably spent a good 2-3 hours churning through the queue, helping out. It's at about this length of time/moment that I thought "This is monotonous and costly. Am I getting anything in return for this beyond the pride of charity?"

I'm not suggesting that reviewing isn't at all rewarding. Anonymous donations are after all a thing. At this point in my day though, I would not continue reviewing without an added incentive. In fact, I'm actually a bit disappointed in the amount of time I've allowed myself to spend sucked into so far today in terms of the cost metric. Where many of us often charge base rates of $100, $200, $300+ for our time, I'm sure many would agree.

I was a bit taken back that the aforelinked question had been closed as "Off-topic" - ironic as a Meta question directly related to the review of the validity of questions themselves.

**Note that:** this question is titled "Award" and not "Award rep," though rep points are the primary reward on this site to date.

**The question is:** Are there any conceivable & useful + relatively secure rewards for reviewing questions?

Some obvious potential answers come to mind:

- A secondary points or ranking system. What benefit it confers is debatable.
- Monetary or cryptocurrency compensation.
- Standard rep points + an anti-robot system that's extremely difficult to game.
- A KYC process for becoming an incentivized reviewer.
- Hand-pick or rank-threshold users from which review-audit questions must be associated in order to be derived.

The viability of any one solution is not implied. Questions & answers are potentially gambled therefore making reviews gamble removes a potential check on the former. This is simply a means to discuss potential solutions.

*I don't know what the review-queue to reviewer ratio is at present.*

If the queue is currently being consumed at a sufficient rate by charity, the stats showing that would be the proper answer. If not, this question seeks to solve it.

On the topic of robot-reviews, consider that there are many good engineers & scientists around here who deal with that proposition daily. Good ideas abound.

Comment: There already is an award for reviewing: badges. And those badges already lead to problems with robo-reviewing. The ideal reviewer is motivated not by recognition, but by a genuine desire to keep the site they are reviewing on clean.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> A secondary points or ranking system.

This already exists, in the form of badges ([Custodian](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/184/custodian), [Reviewer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/169/reviewer) and [Steward](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/185/steward)). There's a badge progress bar at the top of the page; you can click on it to show more badges you can earn:

[image]

These count towards your [candidate score](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/252641/295232) if you would want to run for moderator at any point in the future.

Also, there is a form of ranking on the [statistic page](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/stats) for each queue:

[image]